# How to compile a github project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I wanted to download and compile a Github Android App. I am a web developer with little to no experience with Android Studio. So far I have installed the Android Studio and added the files as in the repo in the studio. But I do not know how to compile these files into an apk file.

Comment: run build->clean project to make sure things are fine.
then build->generate bundle/apk

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can follow below steps

> Step1:

Clone or download github project

[image]

> Step2

Extract it.

[image: iamge]

> Step 3

Open it in Android Studio. File >> Open...

[image: iamge]

> Step 4

After successful build. From toolbar

Build >> Build Apk(s)

[image]

> Where to find that apk?

you can find that apk in your project folder inside

> ~\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk

Comment: You are awesome!